# Angular 2 lost data from http.get request

Tags: angular, http, get

I have a problem with http.get request. 
The data is displayed for 1 second after the request, and then disappear.
component.ts:

```
http.get('http://localhost:52875/api/clients/1').subscribe(result => {
        this.client = result.json();
    });

http.get('http://localhost:52875/api/client_balances/1').subscribe(result => {
        this.cash = result.text();
    });
```

component.html:

```
<p *ngIf="!client"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<form *ngIf="client">
        {{client.first_name}}
        {{client.last_name}}
<br />
        {{cash}}
<br />
<a class="alert-link" [routerLink]="['/cash/add']">Add</a>
<a class="alert-link" [routerLink]="['/cash/out']">Out</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions happening in the browser?

Comment: The code itself seems correct

Comment: There are no exceptions in the broser

Comment: I have found the Error:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:52875/api/products. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50749' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Is your web app hosted on `localhost:50749`? If so, then you are dealing with CORS issue: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing. To solve it, you basically need to allow your `api` to accept requests from other origins

Comment: Yes, i did it already. All works good. thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not give access to the API. I'm using ASP.NET Core. I just opened access to my WEB application in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Added this:
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:50749"));
        });
        //
        Other code
        //
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        // Added this:
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```